# Modify existing column or link to what the change is?

Tags: database, database-design, data, relational-database

I am making a game. In this game people can modify a value of an object. Let's picture it like so.

House is the object

price is the value

Mold is the modifier

Should I reflect changes to the price of the house in the database by directly altering a size column.

```
UPDATE house SET price = price - 2 WHERE id = 1;
```

Or should I link the modifier with a modifier table so that I can keep record of why a price is what it is.

```
-- Psuedo Sql
house.price = abstract.house_price - modifier.mold
```

On the one hand, just altering the column is simple to do and will have faster queries if I have a ton of modifiers, which I will.

On the other hand, if something goes wrong with my math, I'll have a lot of difficulty fixing prices to be what they are suppose to be.

Is it a bad idea to do both?

Comment: The second thing you are describing is called event sourcing and is a good thing if you want to keep the history of changes. If you do not care about the causes of a change a simple update is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did the base price for the house come from?

If the base price is completely free of your modifiers then a base price + sum of modifiers is a fine way to calculate price.

If modifiers can creep into the base price you will want to just update the base price as new information comes in and leave it at that.

How could modifiers creep in? Depends on how you calculate the base price and if you ever create new modifiers that didn't exist before that used to be factored into the base price.

You could sidestep the whole issue by setting base price at 0 and just summing modifiers.  For course the this same problem comes up again if you decide to break up a modifier into multiple modifiers.  In the end, the base price is really just another modifier.

Which leads me to the acid question:

Should changing the value of the mold modifier change the price of houses that already have a mold modifier applied?

You can try to fudge this by applying deltas to precalculated prices but that is brittle.  It's safer to know all the calculations that arrive at a value.  It's just not always practical.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to do both so I can have easy quick querys, but also have a record and stay flexible.

Comment: What I'm describing is exclusive.  You either recalculate when modifiers change or you don't.  You can trace the calculations either way.  If you don't recalculate, you'll need an audit trail to reconstruct how prices were arrived at.

Answer (score 1):

You have two distinct points here.

**Store base + modifiers VS store total**

There is a house priced at 1000$ and two modifiers applied: x2 and +50$. After couple of days since new version hit the market one guy reported that according to his calculations +50$ should be actually +30$.
If you do not have *ordered* history of applied modifiers - you are in trouble, since correct price can be any of ((1000 / 2 - 50) + 30) * 2 = 960$ and (1000 - 50) / 2 * 2 + 30 = 980$.

If you keep only total it would drag you into trouble at least in this border case. Always store detailed information if you have a tiny chance of rewinding modifiers and applying them back.

**Calculate from base + modifiers VS store total + modifiers**

Calculate until performance drops below acceptable level. Then take a look how db performance can be improved, as a last resort introduce a cache for calculated total.

Also have a look at [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529586/should-i-store-a-calculate-value-in-my-database-along-with-the-variables) to get a hint.